# Unknown com_exception error

Tags: php, debugging, comexception

I'm writing an extension for the [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com) which I have [asked on here about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985354/background-script-on-shared-host-with-multiple-php-versions-installed) and someone is reporting the following error:

> com_exception
>
> Description
>
> **Source:** Unknown
> **Description:** Unknown
>   Source File
>
> C:\wamp\www\yiisample\protected\extensions\gallery\EGalleryBase.php(364)

They are using WAMP 5, PHP Version 5.2.1 and Window XP.

Line 364 refers to:

```
$Command = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'EGalleryProcessQueue.php '.$this->_realpath.' '.$this->thumbnailWidth.' '.$this->thumbnailHeight;
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); // <- This line
$WshShell->Run("php.exe $Command", 0, false);
```

But you can see the whole appropriate section in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985354/background-script-on-shared-host-with-multiple-php-versions-installed).

I've checked and `php.exe` wasn't in a defined `PATH`, but even after fixing that, the problem remains.

Google searches almost always point to problems revolving `Word`, or a [PHP bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38719) that doesn't seem to help at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the problem is, or some suggestions as to how I can debug this so that I get more information than "Unknown".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up solving this by running it differently.

**Edit:**

Here's what I used instead.

```
else // Windows
{
    /* Rather than using the original code of:
     * $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
     * $WshShell->Run("php.exe $Command", 0, false);
     * Use:
     */
    pclose(popen("start /B php.exe $Command 2>nul >nul", "r"));
}
```

Comment: How did you run it differently? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28VS.85%29.aspx) simply isn't installed on that particular machine and therefore no WScript.Shell ProgId exists?

Comment: Possibly, I find it unlikely though as it comes installed by default on Windows XP. I'll find out though.