# PHP script hangs if external application called via Wscript.shell throws exception

Tags: c#, php, apache

I m calling console application, `TPDF.exe` made in C# with following PHP code.

```
<?php   
    $myFile=".."; // This variable holds the xml contents 
    $folder=dirname(__FILE__);
    $exe=dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."\\pdfexe\\TPDF.exe";
    $args="\"\"$folder\\$outputfilename\"\" \"\"$folder\\$myFile\"\"";

    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $oShellLink = $WshShell->CreateShortcut("$folder\\temp.lnk");
    $oShellLink->TargetPath = $exe;
    $oShellLink->Arguments = $args;
    $oShellLink->WorkingDirectory = dirname($exe);
    $oShellLink->WindowStyle = 1;
    $oShellLink->Save();
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run("$folder\\temp.lnk", 0, false);
    //$WshShell->Quit();
    $WshShell=null;
    $oShellLink=null;
    $oExec=null;
    unset($WshShell,$oShellLink,$oExec);
    unlink("$folder\\temp.lnk");
?>
```

Everything works fine. But the problem I m facing is if the application `TPDF.exe` throws exception (which I have catched and logged), it makes Apache server irresponsive, literally it hangs the APACHE. I have to stop and restart the APACHE to make it work again.

So what would be feasible solution to avoid this issue? May be I have to make some tweaks on above PHP code or in c# application source code??

P.S.
I haven't posted C# code here because it just works fine, the only issue is apache gets hanged when the application throws exception.

**EDIT:**

Actually its not Apache Server that hangs, its a PHP script that hangs. When I open new tab in a browser and browse same site, it opens correctly. But as soon as a request is made to run external console application and this application throws exception, the page hangs again.

Any help will highly be appreciable.

Comment: Is the code in question designed to throw exceptions on purpose, thus "working fine?"

Comment: @AndrewCounts Well, the exceptions is not thrown on purpose. Application behaves on the basis of user inputs via PHP, so exception is not always thrown. It all depends what user inputs via PHP code. And for time being I can't filter or restrict user inputs. Even sometimes valid user inputs could throw an exception

Comment: Can you use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991630/unknown-com-exception-error instead?

Comment: Does using a try/catch block around your run command pass the external exception back to your PHP script?

Comment: @AndrewCounts it does not, the C# application just logs error into text file

Comment: Right, but apache is hung because it never gets to the unlink... You may not get the exception info but do you get control back in the catch, to unliink in finally?

Comment: @AndrewCounts, No that didn't work either

Comment: why don't you use [exec](http://us3.php.net/function.exec) ? what is the sense in creation of link and using COM?

Comment: @IlyaBursov, yes I have used exec before, but exec didnt work as intended. It lead to frequent hang of the script. I used Com to run the application as process, and with this the script hang up was drastically reduced but not completely eliminated.

Comment: @WatsMyName very strange situation, as external application actually cannot do anything with apache/php as it runs in separate memory space. Did you tried creation of .bat file with tpdf commands in it and then all kind of `exec` `proc_open` `shell_exec` `system` to run `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @WatsMyName what's the purpose on creating a `tmp` file and then invoking it and not invoke your `.exe` file directly? Just to know, I forced and exception and stills working

Comment: @OscarJara, I wanted to pass arguments to an exe. I m not good at `Wscript.shell`. I m not sure whether even that is needed or not. I just used the code found in php.net's user manual

Comment: @WatsMyName there are many ways to invoke an `.exe` file and also a lot of docummentation. Why don't you try something new? if you are facing this, it is a strange behavior, I also tried some days before to replicate what you got (by creating also a C# console app, sleeping the thread for some time and throwing an exception) I never got some kind of problem at server side.

Comment: @OscarJara, I tried same console app, but this time i created a new php page which only calls this console application with same piece of code, without other PHP codes. This time the script was not hung. So seems that I have a problem in the PHP code, where I have lots of operation done along with `Wscript.shell` code.

Comment: @WatsMyName Will be good if you can post all the `PHP` code or related  `classes` to it (the ones you are importing using `require(..)` or something else). If you provide us with that, then we can help you in a better way because If I test what I got here, it's impossible, at least in my case your code is working. Just to know, sometimes if you don't optimize your code, `PHP` starts to consume more and more resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, I found the culprit. The console app creates a blank text file after completing operation...and PHP file checks for that file whether it exists or not. The php script is suspended using sleep function unless that file exist. Since console app broke due to exception, no file was created, the PHP code went to infinite loop, which eventually hung the script.

P.S.
The php code was not done by me and its not my logic, so please don't ask why I did this.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use WShell? PHP has built-in commands for executing external applications.
Is that a viable option or do you have a specific reason not to? If so if you can share that reason, maybe someone can help you achieve your goal in a different way entirely.

I'm assuming you are creating a PDF file there are alternatives to a custom solution:

- http://www.fpdf.org
- http://www.tcpdf.org
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.haru.php (Experimental)

Any reason no to use these?

Next, more aimed at your issue.

Most obviously it appears that you are setting `$oShellLink->WindowStyle = 1;` where 1 means:

> Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when displaying the window for the first time.

I think that is not what you are looking for because it appears you are doing command line execution. Instead set it to `$oShellLink->WindowStyle = 0;`:

> Hides the window and activates another window.

I have some bad experiences with WShell.Run and WShell.Exec, it's a steaming pile you shouldn't touch with a stick from a distance but anyway, here it goes..

About these:

- **`.Run(strCommand, intWindowStyle, bWaitOnReturn)`**

  > Runs a program in a new process. - [.Run on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

  It takes two arguments that seem to make more sense for command line execution, intWindowStyle (let's hide the window..) and bWaitOnReturn (PHP is a sequentially executing language so we want to execute this sequentially too right? not really..).
- **`.Exec(strCommand)`**

  > The Exec method returns a WshScriptExec object, which provides status and error information about a script run with Exec along with access to the **StdIn, StdOut, and StdErr channels**. The Exec method allows the execution of **command line applications only**. The Exec method cannot be used to run remote scripts. Do not confuse the Exec method with the Execute method (of the WshRemote object). - [.Exec on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d33x48a9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

  It only takes 1 argument, the command, then returns an object with neat properties that allow you to control the command line execution process better than `.Run()`.
  This is more useful for command line scripts like yours it seems. It also opens up stdErr etc., so you can do more debugging.

Try `.Exec()` I think it will at least bring you closer to the answer to your problem (because of better debugging methods). You will need to create a loop with a sleep function so you can wait for the process to finish, this way you can easily implement a timeout and regularly check stdErr etc., it makes your application more responsive and more reliable.

Also note that when running command line applications from the command line with `.Run()` you may need to use `%comspec% /c [script]` to run the application in a command prompt window, that can be hidden by setting `intWindowStyle` to 0.

Comment: Yes I m creating PDF for printing purpose. The PDF created has CMYK color profile with custom icc profile attached. Also custom fonts are embedded into PDF

Comment: Also can we send custom message from console app to PHP application that is calling it, like after completing certain operation in c# console app, I want to send a string "success" from console app to PHP??

Comment: Well to say "success" or "fail" you can simply use an exit code right? On Windows even a whole 32 bit signed integer of them, 4294967295 possible exit statuses for every detailed error or success message.

Comment: Yes but, in my case the variable `$oExec` gets `0` as a value, no matter the console app throws exception or works fine. I even tried to send exit code manually like this `Environment.Exit(1)`, this didn't work either.

Comment: Anyway, I found the culprit. The console app creates a blank text files after completing operation...and PHP file checks for that file whether that exists or not. THe php script is suspended using sleep function unless that file exists. Since console app broke due to exception, no file was created, the PHP code went to infinite loop, which eventually hang the script. Anyway seeing your effort on helping my question, I m awarding the bounty points to you

Comment: Great that it solved! Much appreciated, hope some googler might put the comments to good use some day..